# Como calcular a distância Euclidiana

Tags: c++, matemática

Quero calcular a distância euclidiana através da seguinte fórmula:

[image: formula euclidiana]

Então eu tentei, fazendo este código:

```
#define SLEEP_1 1000
void HeaderClass::DistanciaEuclidianaEntrePontos() {

    int x1, x2, y1, y2, distancia;

    std::cout << "Coordenadas ponto 1 (x): ";
    std::cin >> x1;

    std::cout << "Coordenadas ponto 1 (y): ";
    std::cin >> y1;

    Sleep(SLEEP_1);

    std::cout << "Coordenadas ponto 2 (x): ";
    std::cin >> x2;

    std::cout << "Coordenadas ponto 2 (y): ";
    std::cin >> y2;

    Sleep(SLEEP_1);

    distancia = sqrt(((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2));

    std::cout << "Distancia Euclidiana: " << distancia << std::endl;
}
```

mas mesmo assim não consigo obter o que eu quero...

por exemplo:

### √(4-7) ² + (2-5) ² = 12

mas o programa diz :

### √(4-7) ² + (2-5) ² = -214(...)

Existirá alguma maneira mais de o fazer?

Comment: O que você está obtendo desse jeito, e o que esperava obter?

Comment: Não sei bem, dá me um numero enorme, por exemplo : √(4-7) ² + (2-5) ² = 12 mas no programa diz : - 214...

Comment: Dei uma resposta que deve resolver seu problema, mas gostaria de perguntar: é `int` mesmo que você quer, não seria `double`? Assim a distância pode ser truncada, se ela não der um valor inteiro.

Comment: Não pois o double entraria em conflito com o " ^2 " (²)

Comment: @André Não entendi... Você pode calcular o quadrado de um `double` sim, sem problemas...

Comment: Em C/C++ o operador ^ não significa potenciação e sim OU Exclusivo (Bitwise exclusive OR). Utilize a função pow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seu problema está nessa linha:

```
distancia = sqrt(((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2));
```

Em C++, o operador `^` não é a exponenciação, mas o "ou exclusivo" (xor). Você está fazendo o xor da diferença entre os números e `2`, o que é equivalente a mudar o 2º bit do número e só. Em C++ não há um operador de exponenciação, que eu saiba, melhor simplesmente multiplicar a diferença por ela mesma:

```
distancia = sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
```

Comment: @Bacco hehe é, às vezes esses detalhes passam despercebidos... :P P.S. O `pow` seria bom se as sub-expressões tivessem efeitos colaterais, e não pudessem ser usadas duas vezes (o que não é o caso aqui).

Comment: Veja funcionando no IDEONE. http://ideone.com/rlmEy3 Na verdade, se usar o float obtém 4 e uns quebrados (o que faz sentido, pois 4 * 4 = 16, quase 18)

Comment: Pois, no IDEONE dá 4.24264 >.> devido ao facto de usar float

Comment: sim , eu reparei

Comment: +1, embora eu não goste muita da solução de se usar `(x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)` por uma questão de legibilidade de código e por questões relacionadas com arredondamentos para diferenças muito pequenas; tenho de verificar se `hypot(x1-x2,y1-y2)` é preferível a isto no que concerne os arredondamentos.

Answer (score 6):

Eu faria assim, aproveitando a maior parte do seu código, usando `hypot(x,y)` (apenas a partir do C++11) que devolve a raiz quadrada da soma quadrática de `x` e `y`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    double x1, x2, y1, y2, distancia;

    cout << "Coordenadas ponto 1 (x): ";
    cin >> x1;

    cout << "Coordenadas ponto 1 (y): ";
    cin >> y1;

    cout << "Coordenadas ponto 2 (x): ";
    cin >> x2;

    cout << "Coordenadas ponto 2 (y): ";
    cin >> y2;

    distancia = hypot(x1-y1,x2-y2);

    cout << "Distancia Euclidiana: " << distancia << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Note também que tanto as coordenadas dos pontos como a distância não podem ser inteiros (a menos que tenha um espaço discretizado). Uma sugestão interessante seria a de escrever o código válido para um espaço com uma métrica euclidiana a n-dimensões ou para espaços com métricas diferentes.

Comment: +1 Não conhecia esse `hypot`, para usar na prática concordo que seria o melhor. Mas como nesse caso trata-se obviamente de um exercício, imagino que o cálculo explícito é mesmo o mais desejado (seja multiplicando o fator por ele mesmo, seja usando a função de potência).

Comment: @mgibsonbr O C++11 introduz algumas funções novas na `cmath´, em particular as funções hiperbólicas inversas, a raiz cúbica, funções erro e gama, mais algumas de arredondamento, etc. Bem sei que não é do interesse de toda a gente, mas são muito bem vindas. Em relação à sua resposta, creio que foi muito didáctica porque apontou as diferenças dos operadores. Em jeito de confissão: eu preferia que houvesse, de facto, um operador para a exponenciação no C++.

Comment: fica fácil lembrar do nome da função, no fim o resultado é mesmo a hipotenusa.

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer também é criar uma função que faça a exponenciação e usa-lá para calcular o quadrado do número.

Exemplo:

```
int exp (int num){
    return num * num;
}
distancia = sqrt((exp(x2 - x1)) + (exp(y2 - y1)));
```