# Operador da exponenciação em C++

Tags: c++, matemática, operadores

A propósito de uma [questão recentemente colocada e respondida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103464/como-calcular-a-dist%C3%A2ncia-euclidiana/103472#103472): há alguma razão - histórica ou não - para que o C++ (bem como muito outras linguagens de programação) não inclua um operador para a exponenciação?

Por exemplo, quando quero calcular 5 elevado a 7.2 tenho de fazer:

```
#include <cmath>
[...]
resultado=pow(5,7.2);
```

E, se houvesse um operador `op`, faria simplesmente:

```
resultado=5 op 7.2;
```

A resposta a esta questão não deverá ser apenas baseada em opiniões pessoais (essas podem ser discutidas em rodapé nos comentários) mas sim tentar incluir referências que suportem as eventuais razões.

Comment: Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

O motivo histórico provável é porque o C também não tem. E ele não tem, porque originalmente não foi pensado para executar muitas operações matemáticas.

Lembre-se que a linguagem foi criada para escrever um sistema operacional e não resolver problemas científicos. Lembre-se que a linguagem tinha como objetivo melhorar o *Assembly*, que não possuía isto como instrução.

Além disso as máquinas daquela época eram simples e provavelmente não compensava criar um operador. E também não era uma operação comum. Era muito fácil estourar os valores que o processador trabalhava naturalmente, complicando os algoritmos de tal forma que a função dava na mesma.

Já se discutiu a possibilidade de criar o operador para o C++, não há vantagens suficientes para introduzir na linguagem que já é complicada. Não é tão trivial implementá-lo quanto possa parecer, pelo menos não em uma linguagem com este histórico.

Se só a sintaxe interessa, é possível criá-lo:

```
template<typename T>
T operator^(T x, T y) {
    return std::pow(x, y);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/Exponantial.cpp).

Precisa saber se deve, está matando o XOR. E fique de olho na [tabela de precedência](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) dele. Pode ficar esquisito.

Comment: Bela resposta. Mas será que não valeria a pena descrever um pouco mais (nada muito amplo, só alguns poucos detalhes e talvez uma referência externa para mais informações) sobre a passagem "está matando o XOR"? Ela me parece a parte mais importante da sua resposta. :)

Comment: Eu acho a menos importante :), coloquei este exemplo mais como curiosidade, porque não acho que deva fazer isto. Está matando o XOR porque este é o operador de XOR :) Poderia escolher outro, poderia ser mais restritivo no que pode usar esta operação, mas nada disso faz muito sentido, é melhor usar a função.

Comment: Ok, sem erro. :)